# HTTP 406 – Not Acceptable When using RestController Spring MVC 4.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to use `restController` in Spring MVC but I get the error "406 - Not accept".

I try to add jackson-maven, produces,... but I can't resolve this problem. I use spring-webmvc 4.0.6.RELEASE.

Thank you.

Here my code:
**(POM.XML)**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

**(Config Model)**

```
  package com.anews.model;

   import javax.persistence.*;

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "tblconfig")
   public class Config {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       @Column(nullable=false)
       private int config_id;
       private String config_sitename;
       private String config_url;
       private String config_email;
       private String config_logo;

       public Config(){
           config_id=0;
       }

       public Config(int config_id,String config_sitename,String config_url,String config_email,String config_logo){
           super();
           this.config_id = config_id;
           this.config_sitename = config_sitename;
           this.config_url = config_url;
           this.config_email = config_email;
           this.config_logo = config_logo;
}






       public String getConfig_logo() {
           return config_logo;
       }

       public void setConfig_logo(String config_logo) {
           this.config_logo = config_logo;
       }



       public int getConfig_id() {
           return config_id;
       }

public void setConfig_id(int config_id) {
    this.config_id = config_id;
}

public String getConfig_sitename() {
    return config_sitename;
}

public void setConfig_sitename(String config_sitename) {
    this.config_sitename = config_sitename;
}

public String getConfig_url() {
    return config_url;
}

public void setConfig_url(String config_url) {
    this.config_url = config_url;
}

public String getConfig_email() {
    return config_email;
}

public void setConfig_email(String config_email) {
    this.config_email = config_email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Config{" +
            "config_id=" + config_id +
            ", config_sitename='" + config_sitename + '\'' +
            ", config_url='" + config_url + '\'' +
            ", config_email='" + config_email + '\'' +
            ", config_logo='" + config_logo + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

**(ConfigService)**
       package com.anews.service;

```
public interface ConfigService {
    Config getConfig();
}
```

**(ConfigServiceImpl)**

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
    public class aNewsRestController {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigService configService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/a",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =         MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    Config getConfig(){
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setConfig_id(1);
        config.setConfig_email("a");
        config.setConfig_logo("a");
        config.setConfig_sitename("a");
        config.setConfig_url("a");


        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use compatible `jackson` version jars

Comment: any one can tell me which version of jackson is Compatible with spring-mvc 4.0.6

Comment: In my case with `Spring 4.1.6` I'm using `Jackson 2.4.1`, with `spring 4.0.6` you could try `Jackson 2.4.1` or lower

Comment: Spacing and orthography.